# R/Shiny: can changing a value of a reactive trigger an event?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

Is it possible to trigger an event when a reactive changes value?

If you put an observeEvent on an input, changes in the input's value will trigger the event:

`observeEvent(input$val1,{cat("triggered when input$val1 changes)")})`

But if you put an observeEvent on a reactive, the event is only triggered during initialization:

```
  reactiveSum <- reactive({
    as.integer(input$val1) + as.integer(input$val2) + as.integer(input$val3)
  })
  observeEvent(reactiveSum,{cat("only triggers during initialization")})
```

Why do changes in the value of an input trigger an event, but changes in the value of a reactive won't?

Is there a way to trigger an event when the value of a reactive changes?

Comment: You need `reactiveSum()` in your `observeEvent`.  `reactiveSum()` is the *current value* of the reactive, which can change.  `reactiveSum` is the reactive itself, which does not.  It's just a function.

Comment: @Limey good explanation and I think it's worth to write it up as an answer as confusing the reactive itself with the current value of a reactive is a common error in shiny

Comment: @limey, @starja Tested and it works! So simple and yet so elusive, despite my experimentation in adding parentheses. Your explanation that: "reactiveSum() is the current value of the reactive, which can change. reactiveSum is the reactive itself, which does not. It's just a function." finally allowed this concept to click. Part of what's been confusing me that you can't do `input$val1()` ... it throws an error ... but you do add the parentheses to the reactive ... `observeEvent(reactiveSum(),{cat("test2: observeEvent(reactiveSum)", reactiveSum(), "\n")})`

Comment: @limey I agree with starja that your explanation is good and it would be great if you write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the request of @starja and @Eric...

A reactive is simply a function

```
> shiny::reactive
function (x, env = parent.frame(), quoted = FALSE, ..., label = NULL, 
    domain = getDefaultReactiveDomain(), ..stacktraceon = TRUE) 
{
    check_dots_empty()
    x <- get_quosure(x, env, quoted)
    fun <- as_function(x)
    formals(fun) <- list()
    label <- exprToLabel(get_expr(x), "reactive", label)
    o <- Observable$new(fun, label, domain, ..stacktraceon = ..stacktraceon)
    structure(o$getValue, observable = o, cacheHint = list(userExpr = zap_srcref(get_expr(x))), 
        class = c("reactiveExpr", "reactive", "function"))
}
<bytecode: 0x7fdbfa6cb8d8>
<environment: namespace:shiny>
```

(as are `observeEvent` and the like).  If you want `observeEvent` (or similar) to react to a change, you need to pass it something that changes.  `myReactive` is simply the function *itself*, which does not change.  `myReactive()` is the *current value* of the function, which does.  So

```
observeEvent(myReactive(), { ... })
```

works, but

```
observeEvent(myReactive, { ... })
```

does not.

The only time (that I can think of) where you would use the reactive rather than its value is when passing additional parameters to a [module](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html) server function: you pass the reactive (`myReactive`) as a parameter and call it (`myReactive()`) in the body of the server.